# How do I create efficient instance variable mutators in Matlab?

Tags: oop, matlab, this, getter-setter

Previously, I implemented mutators as follows, however it ran spectacularly slowly on a recursive OO algorithm I'm working on, and I suspected it may have been because I was duplicating objects on every function call... is this correct?

```
%% Example Only
obj2 = tripleAllPoints(obj1)
    obj.pts = obj.pts * 3;
    obj2 = obj1
end
```

I then tried implementing mutators without using the output object... however, it appears that in MATLAB i can't do this - the changes won't "stick" because of a scope issue?

```
%% Example Only
tripleAllPoints(obj1)
    obj1.pts = obj1.pts * 3;
end
```

For application purposes, an extremely simplified version of my code (which uses OO and recursion) is below.

```
classdef myslice

properties
    pts     % array of pts
    nROW % number of rows
    nDIM % number of dimensions
    subs    % sub-slices
end % end properties

methods
    function calcSubs(obj)
        obj.subs = cell(1,obj.nROW);
        for i=1:obj.nROW
            obj.subs{i} = myslice;
            obj.subs{i}.pts = obj.pts(1:i,2:end);
        end
    end

    function vol = calcVol(obj)
      if obj.nROW == 1
         obj.volume = prod(obj.pts);
      else
         obj.volume = 0;
         calcSubs(obj);
         for i=1:obj.nROW
                obj.volume = obj.volume + calcVol(obj.subs{i});
         end
      end
    end

end % end methods

end % end classdef
```

Answer (score 4):

Matlab has two types of classes: [handle and value](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfylwk-1.html).

A value class is passed by value, and has thus to be copied whenever you write to it. Also, method calls need to be of the form `obj = method(obj);` in order for the changes to 'stick'.

In contrast, handle objects are passed by reference, and thus, whenever you modify an object in any workspace - base workspace or a function's workspace - the object is changed everywhere. Thus, a call `method(obj);` changes `obj` in the calling workspace as well, even though `obj` is not returned explicitly.

The default class is the value object. If you want to use handle objects, your `classdef` line has to be:

```
classdef myslice < handle
```

i.e. you're subclassing the handle class.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you can give MATLAB an extra hint about what's going on by using the same name for your output as the input. In your example, this avoids creating a copy of `obj`. This may not always be appropriate (for example, if you need both the old and new values of `obj.pts` to update some other property).

```
%% Example Only
obj = tripleAllPoints(obj)
    obj.pts = obj.pts * 3;
end
```

(see also: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/ )